# Array values log into a GUI

Tags: java, swing

I got this code running good in a console, but how can i implement this array log in values using Graphical User Interface (Swing) in Java?

With implement in GUI i mean give the user the change of log in values like the array does, but implemented in a graphical environtment.

```
int[][] array = new int[4][5];

         for(int i = 0; i < array.length; ++i)
             for(int j = 0; j < array[i].length; ++j)
                 array[i][j] = sc.nextInt();

double[][] lhsArray = { {array[0][0],array[0][1],array[0][2],array[0][3]},  {array[1][0],array[1][1],array[1][2],array[1][3]},  {array[2][0],array[2][1],array[2][2],array[2][3]}, {array[3][0],array[3][1],array[3][2],array[3][3]} };
         double[] rhsArray = {array[0][4],array[1][4],array[2][4],array[3][4]};
```

what the above code does is create a Bidimentional array and let the user to log in the values one by one into the 4x4 array, i want implement the same but using GUI, instead of using console.

Comment: Please don't expect anyone here to deliver code for you. Show what you've tried, tell us where you have problems and ask a specific question. You could also get started by going through a [Swing tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/)

Comment: Sorry, your question is very unclear.  We don't know what your code does or is trying to do, and what it would mean to implement it in Swing.

Comment: Start by reading http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/ then write some code.  If you’re having trouble, read the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/overview-summary.html).  If you’re still having trouble, search Stack Overflow for your problem.  If no existing question answers your problem, ask a question of your own or update this one.

Comment: @jimGarrison  what the above code does is create a Bidimentional array and let the user to log in the values one by one into the 4x4 array, i want implement the same but using GUI instead console.

Comment: So you are asking how to create a GUI. That is _far_ beyond the scope of what SO is for, and is very well documented in tutorials on the Web.  Please visit the [help] and especially read [ask] for more information.  SO is not a tutorial site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to use `JTextfield` to catch input values from users, and then use `.getText` to catch the values and then implement in the array!
like :

```
array[0][0] = textFieldName.getText();
array[0][1] = textFieldName.getText();
```

... so on..